# Install font packages for all the language charsets

Tags: command-line, server, fonts, language-support

On a machine running Ubuntu server there is a script that generates pdf files with the website content.

There was a problem that it was not showing the Chinese characters. After installing the Chinese font packages it did work for Chinese.

How can we make sure that all the language characters are handled (e.g. Japanese, Arabic, Hebrew etc)?

How to install the fonts for all the languages?

Comment: All?? I think there are 200+ `fonts-*` packages in the archive. But you can look at the `/usr/share/language-selector/data/pkg_depends` file. The `fn:` entries in that file show which packages are automatically pulled when you install some of the non-latin languages.

Comment: Ah, good point. Well, obviously we'd like to install as few as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look here
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fonts
you can install font packages listed here